# Why is the iteration of the values of a defaultdict still a list?

Tags: python

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)

dd['a'].append(1)
dd['a'].append(2)

for d in dd.values():
    print(d)
```

It prints out `d` as a `list` of `[1,2]`. `dd.values()` should be a `list` and `d` shouldn't be a single value?

Comment: values in your `dict` are `list`. then `d` is a `list`.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, your final dict in this example looks like `{'a': [1, 2]}`.  The keys are `str`s, and the values are `list`s.

Comment: `dd.values` returns an iterable of dict values, even when the dict only has a single key/value pair. You are iterating something similar to `([1,2],)`, not `[1, 2]`.

Comment: `dd.values()` is not a list, it is a set-like view of the values in your dictionary. It is an iterable over the values. In your case, each value is a list, since you used `defaultdict(list)`. Why do you think `d` **shouldn't** be a list?

Answer (score 0):

The values in your `defaultdict` *are* lists.  If you want the values inside *those* lists, you need to do something like:

```
for d in dd.values():
  for x in d:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

A defaultdict created with `defaultdict(list)` uses the function call `list()` to create the new value of any as-yet-unset key. So *every* value of `dd` is a `list` (unless it was explicitly as something else), and `dd.values()` is an iterable over a sequence of `list`s.

Answer (score 0):

`dd.values()` returns a `<class 'dict_values'>` that knows the particulars of the dictionary values, including the ability to iterate them.

The `defaultdict` is setup to create a new empty list when a new key is seen. `dd['a'].append(1)` created the key 'a' and created a list for its value, then did an append to that list. `dd.['a'].append(2)` found that the key already existed and appended to its value (a list with `1` from first access).